# How to add onClickListener on a RecyclerView in Android?

Tags: android

I am developing a car rental app. When user clicks on the the car, he should be directed to a booking page. I tried everything out there but when I click the view / car, I get the following error :
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.cuboid.rentacabs.ViewAdapter$onClickListener.onClick(int)' on a null object reference`

Everything in the code looks just fine to me,
here's my viewAdapter.java

```
public class ViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


DatabaseReference ref;
FirebaseDatabase fbRref;
Context context;
ArrayList<Model> model;
private onClickListener mListener;

public ViewAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Model> listItems, onClickListener onClickListener)
{
    this.context = c;
    this.model = listItems;
    this.mListener = onClickListener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.car_details, parent, false);
    fbRref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref = fbRref.getReference();
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.carName.setText(model.get(position).getmCarName());
    holder.seatingCapacity.setText(model.get(position).getmSeatingCapacity());
    holder.transmission.setText(model.get(position).getmTransmission());
    holder.fuelType.setText(model.get(position).getmFuelType());
    //holder.rate.setText(model.get(position).getmRate());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return model.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
{
    public TextView carName,seatingCapacity,transmission,fuelType,rate;
    public Button bookBtn;
    public onClickListener onClickListener;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        carName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.car_name);
        seatingCapacity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.seating_capacity);
        transmission = itemView.findViewById(R.id.transmission_type);
        fuelType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fuel_type);
        rate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rate);
        bookBtn =(Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_btn);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onClickListener.onClick(getAdapterPosition());
    }
}

public interface onClickListener
{
    void onClick(int position);
}
```

}

this my home fragment:

```
public class home extends Fragment implements ViewAdapter.onClickListener{
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public home() {
}
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static home newInstance() {
    home fragment = new home();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

//to recycler view.
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
public View view;
private ArrayList<Model> listItem;
ViewAdapter Vadapter;
DatabaseReference dbRef;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,false);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.carDetailsContainer);
    listItem = new ArrayList<Model>();
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cars");
    Vadapter = new ViewAdapter(getContext(),listItem,this);
    //recyclerView.OnClickListener();
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                Model model = new Model(ds.child("Name").getValue().toString(),ds.child("Seating_Capacity").getValue().toString(),ds.child("Fuel").getValue().toString(),ds.child("Transmission").getValue().toString(),ds.child("Rate").getValue().toString());
                listItem.add(model);

            }
            recyclerView.setAdapter(Vadapter);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };

    dbRef.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
}

@Override
public void onClick(int position) {
    listItem.get(position);
    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: item"+ position);
    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), booking.class));
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

thanks in advance.

Comment: `itemView.setOnClickListener(this)`  What does that line do ?

Comment: Can you please tell me how it is done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did a small mistake.
just replace this

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onClickListener.onClick(getAdapterPosition());
    }
```

To this

```
  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mListener.onClick(getAdapterPosition());
    }
```

Comment: yes, i don't understand why `viewholder` class is static and also he is using `onClicklistner` which is not assigned.

Comment: @Parth yeah i got it, i dont know y I made that static

Answer (score 0):

Use it Like this as shown below:

```
 itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == id of itemView(R.id.itemview)){
        //do not use this
        onClickListener.onClick(getAdapterPosition());
       //just call the function you need to call on Click of itemview
}
    }
```

Hope this helps